# Is there any XPages Debug Toolbar (Mark Leusink's addin) User documentation out there? (if any)

Tags: xpages

I was looking specifically for a way to write messages to Mark's toolbar from within an XPage source code. I'm able to write messages from within JAVA class files into the toolbar message queue  using this syntax -->

Example:

```
DebugToolbarBean.get().info("<write a message here to display under Messages in the Debug toolbar");
```

Any documentation would be helpful to the community.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Documentation is available at https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPage%20Debug%20Toolbar.

As stated in the documentation you can use the dBar bean in order to write messages from server side JS. Example: `dBar.info( msg );`.