# Calling the Hashtable Get method on an ApplicationScope stored Hashtable - JAVA/XPages

Tags: xpages

I have a number of individually named Hashtables residing in the ApplicationScope space. I'm struggling with the Hashtable's GET(String) method when used in a different Class elsewhere in my app.

My syntax is yelling --> "The method get(String) is undefined for the type FooterLinkBean".

My JAVA code containing this error is --> packedString = gr_footerlink.get(searchKey); where the 'searchKey' is my 'Key' value that I'm attempting to query against my Hashtables named 'Gr_footerlink.get'.

I'm trying to retrieve the value (which is a pipe-delimited string of text values) that I'll later split into their individual components. Both my Hashtables 'Gr_footerlink.get' structure is built in the ApplicationScope space while my method I'm using to call it resides in a SessionScope Managed bean.

I can successfully query the Hashtable immediately after it is built and populated by virtue of writing debug messages into Greg's Xpages Debug Toolbar. However, when I attempt to query the same Hashtables "outside" from a different Class file, it starts yelling at me.

Clearly, I'm confused.

I've tried instantiating a object from by GR_footerlink Bean within my dialogBoxModal Class, thinking that would be enough to expose it's methods, although that seems logical, I am probably not executing it correctly (novice JAVA developer).

Comment: _My syntax is yelling --> "The method get(String) is undefined for the type FooterLinkBean"._ I can't tell you why that is without seeing the code for class `FooterLinkBean`. I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the relevant code (as text and not as an image and neither a link to the code).

Comment: _where the 'searchKey' is my 'Key' value_ Do you mean that the type of variable `searchKey` is `Key`? If so, then is `Key` a class that you wrote?

Comment: _Greg's Xpages Debug Toolbar_ Forgive me but I don't know what that is.

Comment: _Clearly, I'm confused._ You're not the only one. Consider posting a [mcve]. I also suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to learn how this website works and also see [ask] because in my opinion, your question is very poor. (Refer to my previous comments to understand why.)

Comment: The error message says that the method get(String) is undefined for the type FooterLinkBean Please show us the code where you call the undefined get method on FooterLinkBean

Comment: I also don't know what Greg's XPages Debug Toolbar is ;-)

Comment: We definitely need a community post about Greg's XPages Debug Toolbar. Sound's mega. ;-)

Comment: @MarkLeusink The author of the question is aware of where XPages Debug Toolbar originates from :-) https://stackoverflow.com/q/70151342/785061

Comment: That's handy. Nice one.